# printing "grep -o" output in single line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, xargs

How to print output of `grep -o` in a single line ?  I am trying to print :

```
$ echo "Hello Guys!" |grep -E '[A-Z]'
Hello Guys!
$ echo "Hello Guys!" |grep -Eo '[A-Z]' <----Multiple lines
H
G
$ echo "Hello Guys!" |grep -Eo '[A-Z]'
```

Desired output:

```
HG
```

I am able to cheaply achieve it using following command ,but the issue is that number of letters(3 in this case) could be dynamic. So this approach cannot be used.

```
echo "HEllo Guys!" |grep -oE  '[A-Z]' |xargs -L3 |sed 's/ //g'
HEG
```

Comment: This is by definition what `-o` does ---> `Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line`.

Comment: Could use sed. `echo "Hello Guys!" |sed  's/[^A-Z]//g'`

Comment: @123, thanks .Your solution worked for me.

Comment: cannot use perl though ..

Comment: @user5584716 How come?

Comment: restricted to bash only solution as per project requirement.

Comment: Can you please explain , sed part of your comment and put it in answer ?

Comment: @user5584716 sed isn't bash...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it all with this *sed* instruction

```
echo "Hello Guys!" |sed 's/[^A-Z]//g'
```

**UPDATE**

Breakdown of sed command:

The *s///* is *sed*'s substitute command. It simply replaces the first RegEx (the one between the first and the second slash) with the Expression between slash two and three. The trailing *g* stands for global, i.e, do this for every match of the RegEx in the current line. Without the *g* it would just stop processing after the first match. The RegEx itself is matching any non-capital letter and then those letters are replaced with nothing, i.e., effectively deleted.

Comment: I was going to post this but it is limited in that you can only use it match individual characters, it would become far more complicated for words.

Comment: @123 I honestly did not see your comment when I posted it, did not mean to steal your idea. Anyway, the OP did not state that he wants to match whole words. Only that the number of capital letters in might vary.

Comment: thank you for explanation, I assume "^" means negation , is it right ?

Comment: @user5584716 Correct, '^' inside brackets (character class) means negation. Outside of a character class it marks the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **awk**:

```
echo "Hello Guys!" | awk '{ gsub(/[^A-Z]/,"", $0); print;}'
HG
```

Also with **tr**:

```
echo "Hello Guys!" | tr -cd [:upper:]
HG
```

Also with **sed** :

```
echo "Hello Guys!" | sed 's/[^\[:upper:]]//g'
HG
```

Comment: This will also leave the prompt on the same line.

Comment: I don't get your comment

Comment: It doesn't leave a trailing newline so the prompt will start right after the string.

Comment: I put another answer with tr

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove the newline characters. You can use `tr` for that:

```
echo "HEllo Guys!" |grep -Eo '[A-Z]' |tr -d '\n'
HEG
```

Though, it cuts the last newline too.

Comment: @monk That's becuase the last newline char is cut too i.e there is no newline between the output and the next command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl instead of grep

```
echo 'HEllo Guys!' | perl -lne 'print /([A-Z])/g' 
HEG
```